# How to Construct a New Matrix with Specified Rows from some given Matrices in R?

Tags: r

I have 3 matrices(m1, m2, m3 say). There are some elements(say n elements) in column 1 of each matrix which are common to all three. Now I need to construct a matrix whose 1st column consists of those n common elements, and the matrix looks like

```
common element 1, corresponding row of m1, corr. row of m2, corr. row of m3
common element 2,`corr row of m1,  corr row of m2, corr row of m3
        .                .              .               .
        .                .              .               .
        .                .              .               .
common element n  corr row of m1, corr row of m2, corr row of m3
```

I need to do this in R. Please help

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of this code (untested in the absence of the reproducible example that you failed to include.)

```
com12 <- m1[,1][ m[,1] %in% m2[,2] ]
com123 <- com12[ com12 %in% m2[,3] ]
cbind( com123, which(com123 %in% m1[,1]), 
               which(com123 %in% m1[,2]),
               which(com123 %in% m1[,3]) )
```